# The formatting of my resulting HTML (from XML/XSL)

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I have this XML data file:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="CounselForm.xsl"?>
<CounselForm Name="A N OTHER">
    <StudyPoint Assigned="0" Completed="0">
        <Number>1</Number>
        <Description>Accurate Reading</Description>
    </StudyPoint>
    <StudyPoint Assigned="0" Completed="0">
        <Number>2</Number>
        <Description>Words Clearly Spoken</Description>
    </StudyPoint>
    <StudyPoint Assigned="0" Completed="0">
        <Number>3</Number>
        <Description>Correct Pronunciation</Description>
    </StudyPoint>
    <StudyPoint Assigned="0" Completed="0">
        <Number>4</Number>
        <Description>Fluent Delivery</Description>
    </StudyPoint>
    <StudyPoint Assigned="0" Completed="0">
        <Number>5</Number>
        <Description>Appropriate Pausing</Description>
    </StudyPoint>
    <StudyPoint Assigned="0" Completed="0">
        <Number>6</Number>
        <Description>Proper Sense Stress</Description>
    </StudyPoint>
    <StudyPoint Assigned="0" Completed="0">
        <Number>7</Number>
        <Description>Principal Ideas Emphasized</Description>
    </StudyPoint>
    <StudyPoint Assigned="0" Completed="0">
        <Number>8</Number>
        <Description>Suitable Volume</Description>
    </StudyPoint>
    <StudyPoint Assigned="0" Completed="0">
        <Number>9</Number>
        <Description>Modulation</Description>
    </StudyPoint>
    <StudyPoint Assigned="0" Completed="0">
        <Number>10</Number>
        <Description>Enthusiasm</Description>
    </StudyPoint>
    <StudyPoint Assigned="0" Completed="0">
        <Number>11</Number>
        <Description>Warmth And Feeling</Description>
    </StudyPoint>
    <StudyPoint Assigned="1" Completed="0">
        <Number>12</Number>
        <Description>Gestures and Facial Expressions</Description>
        <StartDate>07/03/2016</StartDate>
    </StudyPoint>
    <StudyPoint Assigned="0" Completed="0">
        <Number>13</Number>
        <Description>Visual Contact</Description>
    </StudyPoint>
    <StudyPoint Assigned="0" Completed="0">
        <Number>14</Number>
        <Description>Naturalness</Description>
    </StudyPoint>
    <StudyPoint Assigned="0" Completed="0">
        <Number>15</Number>
        <Description>Good Personal Appearance</Description>
    </StudyPoint>
    <StudyPoint Assigned="0" Completed="0">
        <Number>16</Number>
        <Description>Poise</Description>
    </StudyPoint>
    <StudyPoint Assigned="0" Completed="0">
        <Number>17</Number>
        <Description>Use of Microphone</Description>
    </StudyPoint>
    <StudyPoint Assigned="0" Completed="0">
        <Number>18</Number>
        <Description>Use of Bible in Replying</Description>
    </StudyPoint>
    <StudyPoint Assigned="0" Completed="0">
        <Number>19</Number>
        <Description>Use of Bible Encouraged</Description>
    </StudyPoint>
    <StudyPoint Assigned="0" Completed="0">
        <Number>20</Number>
        <Description>Scriptures Effectively Introduced</Description>
    </StudyPoint>
    <StudyPoint Assigned="0" Completed="0">
        <Number>21</Number>
        <Description>Scriptures Read With Proper Emphasis</Description>
    </StudyPoint>
    <StudyPoint Assigned="0" Completed="0">
        <Number>22</Number>
        <Description>Scriptures Correctly Applied</Description>
    </StudyPoint>
    <StudyPoint Assigned="0" Completed="0">
        <Number>23</Number>
        <Description>Practical Value Made Clear</Description>
    </StudyPoint>
    <StudyPoint Assigned="0" Completed="0">
        <Number>24</Number>
        <Description>Choice of Words</Description>
    </StudyPoint>
    <StudyPoint Assigned="0" Completed="0">
        <Number>25</Number>
        <Description>Use of an Outline</Description>
    </StudyPoint>
    <StudyPoint Assigned="0" Completed="0">
        <Number>26</Number>
        <Description>Logical Development of Material</Description>
    </StudyPoint>
    <StudyPoint Assigned="0" Completed="0">
        <Number>27</Number>
        <Description>Extemporaneous Delivery</Description>
    </StudyPoint>
    <StudyPoint Assigned="0" Completed="0">
        <Number>28</Number>
        <Description>Conversational Manner</Description>
    </StudyPoint>
    <StudyPoint Assigned="0" Completed="0">
        <Number>29</Number>
        <Description>Voice Quality</Description>
    </StudyPoint>
    <StudyPoint Assigned="0" Completed="0">
        <Number>30</Number>
        <Description>Interest Shown in the Other Person</Description>
    </StudyPoint>
    <StudyPoint Assigned="0" Completed="0">
        <Number>31</Number>
        <Description>Respect Shown to Others</Description>
    </StudyPoint>
    <StudyPoint Assigned="0" Completed="0">
        <Number>32</Number>
        <Description>Expressed With Conviction</Description>
    </StudyPoint>
    <StudyPoint Assigned="0" Completed="0">
        <Number>33</Number>
        <Description>Tactful Yet Firm</Description>
    </StudyPoint>
    <StudyPoint Assigned="0" Completed="0">
        <Number>34</Number>
        <Description>Upbuilding And Positive</Description>
    </StudyPoint>
    <StudyPoint Assigned="0" Completed="0">
        <Number>35</Number>
        <Description>Repetition for Emphasis</Description>
    </StudyPoint>
    <StudyPoint Assigned="0" Completed="0">
        <Number>36</Number>
        <Description>Theme Developed</Description>
    </StudyPoint>
    <StudyPoint Assigned="0" Completed="0">
        <Number>37</Number>
        <Description>Main Points Made to Stand Out</Description>
    </StudyPoint>
    <StudyPoint Assigned="0" Completed="0">
        <Number>38</Number>
        <Description>Interest - Arousing Introduction</Description>
    </StudyPoint>
    <StudyPoint Assigned="0" Completed="0">
        <Number>39</Number>
        <Description>Effective Conclusion</Description>
    </StudyPoint>
    <StudyPoint Assigned="0" Completed="0">
        <Number>40</Number>
        <Description>Accuracy of Statement</Description>
    </StudyPoint>
    <StudyPoint Assigned="0" Completed="0">
        <Number>41</Number>
        <Description>Understandable to Others</Description>
    </StudyPoint>
    <StudyPoint Assigned="0" Completed="0">
        <Number>42</Number>
        <Description>Informative to Your Audience</Description>
    </StudyPoint>
    <StudyPoint Assigned="0" Completed="0">
        <Number>43</Number>
        <Description>Use of Assigned Material</Description>
    </StudyPoint>
    <StudyPoint Assigned="0" Completed="0">
        <Number>44</Number>
        <Description>Effective Use of Questions</Description>
    </StudyPoint>
    <StudyPoint Assigned="0" Completed="0">
        <Number>45</Number>
        <Description>Illustrations / Examples That Teach</Description>
    </StudyPoint>
    <StudyPoint Assigned="0" Completed="0">
        <Number>46</Number>
        <Description>Illustrations From Familiar Situations</Description>
    </StudyPoint>
    <StudyPoint Assigned="0" Completed="0">
        <Number>47</Number>
        <Description>Effective Use of Visual Aids</Description>
    </StudyPoint>
    <StudyPoint Assigned="0" Completed="0">
        <Number>48</Number>
        <Description>Reasoning Manner</Description>
    </StudyPoint>
    <StudyPoint Assigned="0" Completed="0">
        <Number>49</Number>
        <Description>Sound Arguments Given</Description>
    </StudyPoint>
    <StudyPoint Assigned="0" Completed="0">
        <Number>50</Number>
        <Description>Effort To Reach the Heart</Description>
    </StudyPoint>
    <StudyPoint Assigned="0" Completed="0">
        <Number>51</Number>
        <Description>Accurately Timed, Properly Proportioned</Description>
    </StudyPoint>
</CounselForm>
```

This is the current XSL file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" version="4.01"
    doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"
    doctype-public="//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
        <title>
          Counsel Form
        </title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <h1>
          Counsel Form for <xsl:value-of select="/CounselForm/@Name"/>
        </h1>
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <td>Study Point</td>
              <td>Date Assigned</td>
              <td>Date Completed</td>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="CounselForm/StudyPoint"/>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="StudyPoint">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="Number"/>
        &#160;
        <xsl:value-of select="Description"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="@Assigned=1">
            <xsl:value-of select="StartDate"/>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            &#160;
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="@Completed=1">
            <xsl:value-of select="EndDate"/>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            &#160;
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Now, when I look at this in Internet Explorer and view the source, why does it have so much excessive whitespace?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
<title>
          Counsel Form
        </title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>
          Counsel Form for A N OTHER</h1>
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<td>Study Point</td>
<td>Date Assigned</td>
<td>Date Completed</td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr xmlns="">
<td>1
         
        Accurate Reading</td>
<td>
             
          </td>
<td>
             
          </td>
</tr>
<tr xmlns="">
<td>2
         
        Words Clearly Spoken</td>
<td>
             
          </td>
<td>
             
          </td>
</tr>
<tr xmlns="">
<td>3
         
        Correct Pronunciation</td>
<td>
             
          </td>
<td>
             
          </td>
</tr>
<tr xmlns="">
<td>4
         
        Fluent Delivery</td>
<td>
             
          </td>
<td>
             
          </td>
</tr>
<tr xmlns="">
<td>5
         
        Appropriate Pausing</td>
<td>
             
          </td>
<td>
             
          </td>
</tr>
<tr xmlns="">
<td>6
         
        Proper Sense Stress</td>
<td>
             
          </td>
<td>
             
          </td>
</tr>
<tr xmlns="">
<td>7
         
        Principal Ideas Emphasized</td>
<td>
             
          </td>
<td>
             
          </td>
</tr>
<tr xmlns="">
<td>8
         
        Suitable Volume</td>
<td>
             
          </td>
<td>
             
          </td>
</tr>
<tr xmlns="">
<td>9
         
        Modulation</td>
<td>
             
          </td>
<td>
             
          </td>
</tr>
<tr xmlns="">
<td>10
         
        Enthusiasm</td>
<td>
             
          </td>
<td>
             
          </td>
</tr>
<tr xmlns="">
<td>11
         
        Warmth And Feeling</td>
<td>
             
          </td>
<td>
             
          </td>
</tr>
<tr xmlns="">
<td>12
         
        Gestures and Facial Expressions</td>
<td>07/03/2016</td>
<td>
             
          </td>
</tr>
<tr xmlns="">
<td>13
         
        Visual Contact</td>
<td>
             
          </td>
<td>
             
          </td>
</tr>
<tr xmlns="">
<td>14
         
        Naturalness</td>
<td>
             
          </td>
<td>
             
          </td>
</tr>
<tr xmlns="">
<td>15
         
        Good Personal Appearance</td>
<td>
             
          </td>
<td>
             
          </td>
</tr>
<tr xmlns="">
<td>16
         
        Poise</td>
<td>
             
          </td>
<td>
             
          </td>
</tr>
<tr xmlns="">
<td>17
         
        Use of Microphone</td>
<td>
             
          </td>
<td>
             
          </td>
</tr>
<tr xmlns="">
<td>18
         
        Use of Bible in Replying</td>
<td>
             
          </td>
<td>
             
          </td>
</tr>
<tr xmlns="">
<td>19
         
        Use of Bible Encouraged</td>
<td>
             
          </td>
<td>
             
          </td>
</tr>
<tr xmlns="">
<td>20
         
        Scriptures Effectively Introduced</td>
<td>
             
          </td>
<td>
             
          </td>
</tr>
<tr xmlns="">
<td>21
         
        Scriptures Read With Proper Emphasis</td>
<td>
             
          </td>
<td>
             
          </td>
</tr>
<tr xmlns="">
<td>22
         
        Scriptures Correctly Applied</td>
<td>
             
          </td>
<td>
             
          </td>
</tr>
<tr xmlns="">
<td>23
         
        Practical Value Made Clear</td>
<td>
             
          </td>
<td>
             
          </td>
</tr>
<tr xmlns="">
<td>24
         
        Choice of Words</td>
<td>
             
          </td>
<td>
             
          </td>
</tr>
<tr xmlns="">
<td>25
         
        Use of an Outline</td>
<td>
             
          </td>
<td>
             
          </td>
</tr>
<tr xmlns="">
<td>26
         
        Logical Development of Material</td>
<td>
             
          </td>
<td>
             
          </td>
</tr>
<tr xmlns="">
<td>27
         
        Extemporaneous Delivery</td>
<td>
             
          </td>
<td>
             
          </td>
</tr>
<tr xmlns="">
<td>28
         
        Conversational Manner</td>
<td>
             
          </td>
<td>
             
          </td>
</tr>
<tr xmlns="">
<td>29
         
        Voice Quality</td>
<td>
             
          </td>
<td>
             
          </td>
</tr>
<tr xmlns="">
<td>30
         
        Interest Shown in the Other Person</td>
<td>
             
          </td>
<td>
             
          </td>
</tr>
<tr xmlns="">
<td>31
         
        Respect Shown to Others</td>
<td>
             
          </td>
<td>
             
          </td>
</tr>
<tr xmlns="">
<td>32
         
        Expressed With Conviction</td>
<td>
             
          </td>
<td>
             
          </td>
</tr>
<tr xmlns="">
<td>33
         
        Tactful Yet Firm</td>
<td>
             
          </td>
<td>
             
          </td>
</tr>
<tr xmlns="">
<td>34
         
        Upbuilding And Positive</td>
<td>
             
          </td>
<td>
             
          </td>
</tr>
<tr xmlns="">
<td>35
         
        Repetition for Emphasis</td>
<td>
             
          </td>
<td>
             
          </td>
</tr>
<tr xmlns="">
<td>36
         
        Theme Developed</td>
<td>
             
          </td>
<td>
             
          </td>
</tr>
<tr xmlns="">
<td>37
         
        Main Points Made to Stand Out</td>
<td>
             
          </td>
<td>
             
          </td>
</tr>
<tr xmlns="">
<td>38
         
        Interest - Arousing Introduction</td>
<td>
             
          </td>
<td>
             
          </td>
</tr>
<tr xmlns="">
<td>39
         
        Effective Conclusion</td>
<td>
             
          </td>
<td>
             
          </td>
</tr>
<tr xmlns="">
<td>40
         
        Accuracy of Statement</td>
<td>
             
          </td>
<td>
             
          </td>
</tr>
<tr xmlns="">
<td>41
         
        Understandable to Others</td>
<td>
             
          </td>
<td>
             
          </td>
</tr>
<tr xmlns="">
<td>42
         
        Informative to Your Audience</td>
<td>
             
          </td>
<td>
             
          </td>
</tr>
<tr xmlns="">
<td>43
         
        Use of Assigned Material</td>
<td>
             
          </td>
<td>
             
          </td>
</tr>
<tr xmlns="">
<td>44
         
        Effective Use of Questions</td>
<td>
             
          </td>
<td>
             
          </td>
</tr>
<tr xmlns="">
<td>45
         
        Illustrations / Examples That Teach</td>
<td>
             
          </td>
<td>
             
          </td>
</tr>
<tr xmlns="">
<td>46
         
        Illustrations From Familiar Situations</td>
<td>
             
          </td>
<td>
             
          </td>
</tr>
<tr xmlns="">
<td>47
         
        Effective Use of Visual Aids</td>
<td>
             
          </td>
<td>
             
          </td>
</tr>
<tr xmlns="">
<td>48
         
        Reasoning Manner</td>
<td>
             
          </td>
<td>
             
          </td>
</tr>
<tr xmlns="">
<td>49
         
        Sound Arguments Given</td>
<td>
             
          </td>
<td>
             
          </td>
</tr>
<tr xmlns="">
<td>50
         
        Effort To Reach the Heart</td>
<td>
             
          </td>
<td>
             
          </td>
</tr>
<tr xmlns="">
<td>51
         
        Accurately Timed, Properly Proportioned</td>
<td>
             
          </td>
<td>
             
          </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

What do I need to change in my XSL document so that the resulting HTML looks more elegant?

Thank you.

Andrew

Comment: Define "more elegant". XSLT will produce the HTML you want - but first you need to know what you want. If you want to have styling, then add some CSS. At its current form, your question is not about programming.

Comment: All that excessive whitespace in the output.

Comment: Like, the result being `<td>2 Words Clearly Spoken</td>` instead of split over 3 lines.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood your purpose: you want a better looking **code** (as opposed to the **rendered** HTML)? What difference does it make?

Comment: Correct. :) It makes absolutely no difference! It is my obsessive compulsive disorder! It just looked untidy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a more compact code at the output, place all your literal text nodes within `<xsl:text>` instructions - for example, change:

```
<title>
  Counsel Form
</title>
```

to:

```
<title>
  <xsl:text>Counsel Form</xsl:text>
</title>
```

or remove the white space so:

```
<title>Counsel Form</title>
```

---

*Unrelated to your question, but you have a namespace issue: your table rows and their descendants are in no-namespace, while the table and its ancestors are in the XHTML namespace: you should declare the XHTML namespace as the default namespace at the stylesheet level.*

Comment: Namespace issue: Do you mean **<tr xmlns="">** ? That was done by IE as I don't specify anything myself other than at the start. In other words, I am not really sure what you mean.

Comment: Also, How do I apply this xsl:text with the code further down where I show the study point and description?

Comment: "*Do you mean <tr xmlns=""> ?*" Yes. That was not done by IE, it's done by your stylesheet. You should add `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` to your `xsl:stylesheet` element.

Comment: "*How do I apply this xsl:text with the code further down*" Same way: wrap every literal text in `xsl:text`: instead of `&#160;` use `<xsl:text>&#160;</xsl:text>`.